# Filter records based on current user in PowerApps

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps

I want to filter records on my browse screen with email of current user.I used Office 365 Users Connection.

Logic Which I have written on items property of browse screen:

```
SortByColumns(Search(Filter('Time Entries', User().Email= Office365Users.MyProfile().Mail) , TextSearchBox1.Text, "cf_name"), "createdon", If(SortDescending1,  Ascending,Descending))
```

Error:

> Part of this filter cannot be evaluated remotely due to service limitations.The local evaluation may produce suboptimal or partial results.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Onstart of your app to Set(CurrentUser,User()) and then instead of User().Email = Office365Users.Myprofile().Mail use CurrentUser.Email = Office365Users.Myprofile()